# Does Haskell have a greedy zip (one preserving all elements)?

Tags: haskell

I'm not exactly sure if my nomenclature is correct here, but I was wondering if there was a zip function in Haskell that was greedy. This means that if I had

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5]
zip' a b
#=> [(Just 1, Just 4),(Just 2, Just 5),(Just 3, Nothing)]
```

...where `zip'` is the greedy zip function, it would return a list of tuples the length of the longer list, and where the longer list has an element, but the shorter list does not `Nothing` is put in the respective tuple position. I am not asking how to write this, but instead was wondering if this exists as a built-in.

Here is my implementation (which is probably not great)

```
zip' :: [a] -> [b] -> [(Maybe a, Maybe b)]
zip' (a:xs) [] = (Just a, Nothing) : zip' xs []
zip' [] (b:ys) = (Nothing, Just b) : zip' [] ys
zip' [] _ = []
zip' (a:xs) (b:ys) = (Just a, Just b) : zip' xs ys
```

Comment: search by signature.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'm sorry. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/

Comment: @EliSadoff Go to hoogle and search for the expected type signature of the function.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I didn't find anything for the signature `[a] -> [b] -> [(Maybe a, Maybe b)]`, so I'm guessing it does not exist.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A greedy zip can be neatly expressed through a non-exclusive disjunction type (as opposed to `Either`, which is an exclusive disjunction). Two popular packages offer that. One is the minimalist, dependency-free [*data-or*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-or-1.0.0.5/docs/Data-Or.html):

```
GHCi> import Data.Or
GHCi> :t zipOr
zipOr :: [a] -> [b] -> [Or a b]
GHCi> zipOr [1, 2, 3] [4, 5]
[Both 1 4,Both 2 5,Fst 3]
```

The other is [*these*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.3/docs/Data-Align.html), which comes with lots of bells and whistles:

```
GHCi> import Data.These 
GHCi> import Data.Align
GHCi> :t align
align :: Align f => f a -> f b -> f (These a b)
GHCi> align [1, 2, 3] [4, 5]
[These 1 4,These 2 5,This 3]
```

I believe `Or a b` and `These a b` express your intent better than `(Maybe a, Maybe b)` (the latter type includes `(Nothing, Nothing)`, which a greedy zip will never produce). Still, you can express your `zip'` using either `zipOrWith` from `Data.Or`...

```
import Data.Or

zip' :: [a] -> [b] -> [(Maybe a, Maybe b)]
zip' = zipOrWith $ \xy -> case xy of
    Both x y -> (Just x, Just y)
    Fst x -> (Just x, Nothing)
    Snd y -> (Nothing, Just y)
```

... or `alignWith` from `Data.Align`:

```
import Data.These
import Data.Align

zip' :: Align f => f a -> f b -> f (Maybe a, Maybe b)
zip' = alignWith $ \xy -> case xy of
    These x y -> (Just x, Just y)
    This x -> (Just x, Nothing)
    That y -> (Nothing, Just y)
```

`Data.Align`, in fact, provides your function under the name of [`padZip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.3/docs/Data-Align.html#v:padZip).

Comment: Wow! `Or` is a better idea. Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems that `align` provides precisely the desired function already - `padZip  :: Align f => f a -> f b -> f (Maybe a, Maybe b)` - but as you say, `Or a b` expresses the intent better than `(Maybe a, Maybe b)` anyways.

Comment: @user2407038 Well spotted. I have added that to the answer; thank you.