# Cannot form a list of tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

So my code tries to read pairs of `Int`s and turn them into a list:

```
import Control.Monad (forM, forM_)
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List     (nub)

main = do
    t <- readLn
    forM_ [1..t] (\_ -> do
        n <- readLn
        points <- forM [1..n] (\_ -> do
            pointStr <- getLine
            let [x, y] = map read $ words pointStr
            return (x, y))
        putStrLn $ if check points then "YES" else "NO")

check :: [(Int, Int)] -> Bool
check points = ((==) `on` length) (nub $ map fst points) points
```

However, GHC complains that

```
   • Couldn't match type ‘(Int, Int)’ with ‘Int’
     Expected type: [Int]
       Actual type: [(Int, Int)]
   • In the second argument of ‘(==) `on` length’, namely ‘points’
     In the expression: ((==) `on` length) (nub $ map fst points) points
     In an equation for ‘check’:
       check points = ((==) `on` length) (nub $ map fst points) points
     |
  16 | check points = ((==) `on` length) (nub $ map fst points) points
     |                                                          ^^^^^^
```

I have tried to add a type declaration around `read`, but that doesn't work either. If I replace `return (x, y)` with `return x`, I get the same error. It seems like GHC recognizes `(x, y)` as an `Int`, rather than `(Int, Int)`.

Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I think you are talking about converting tuple pairs to list pairs or a linear list of numbers.
First, this is a list comprehension to convert tuple pairs to list pairs. Second just put a 'concat' before the comprehension to get a linear list.
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >  [ [a,b] | (a,b) <- zip [1..15] [16..30] ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is not with forming the list - the error shows line 16, which is the check function.  Looking there we see:

```
check :: [(Int, Int)] -> Bool
check points = ((==) `on` length) (nub $ map fst points) points
```

Notice the type of your equality function:

```
((==) `on` length) :: Foldable t => t a -> t a -> Bool
```

So you need to provide two arguments of the same type (advanced note: `on` would need to use RankNTypes to allow length to apply to arguments of different types).  However, you provide arguments of two different types (`[Int]` and `[(Int,Int)]`).  Stop trying to be fancy and just do the readable solution:

```
length (nub (map fst points)) == length points
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you the problem is in `check`, and not in `main` (in particular, it doesn't have to do with `read` or `return`). More specifically, it says the type mismatch happens in the second argument of `` (==) `on` length ``. That being so, it is a good idea to have a look at what the type of `` (==) `on` length `` is:

```
GHCi> :t (==) `on` length
(==) `on` length :: Foldable t => t a -> t a -> Bool
```

That tells us both lists must have the same element type, which isn't the case in your `check` -- ergo "Couldn't match type `(Int, Int)` with `Int`". `on` accepts a single arbitrary projection function (`length`, in your case), and so the only way it can be ensured that the projection can be applied to both arguments is if they have the same type:

```
GHCi> :t on
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
```

There is no way the type system can make use of the fact that, in your specific case,  `length` can be applied to lists regardless of the element type and so the difference between the types of the arguments is irrelevant.

The simplest solution to this difficulty is giving up on `on`:

```
check points = length (nub (map fst points)) == length points
```

Alternatively, you can apply `map fst` on both sides -- the element values don't matter except for `nub`, so it doesn't make a difference

```
check points = ((==) `on` length) (nub xCoords) xCoords
    where
    xCoords = map fst points
```

A more explicit way of achieving the same effect is with `void` from `Data.Functor`, which can be used to discard list elements:

```
check points = ((==) `on` length) (void . nub $ map fst points) (void points)
```

Finally, there is the option of switching to a different algorithm altogether. That makes an improvement possible: `check` can be performed by running through just the shortest list, rather than both of them (as using `length` twice demands). You might want to have a go at implementing that. For the sake of illustration, here is a fancy solution which exploits [`These`, the exclusive disjunction type provided by the *these* package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.4/docs/Data-These.htm%C3%A7).

```
import Data.List (nub)
import Data.Align (align)
import Data.These (isThese)

check :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> Bool
check pairs = null . dropWhile isThese $ align (nub . map fst $ pairs) pairs
```

`align` can be succinctly described as a greedy `zip`. For extra commentary on that, cf. [*Does Haskell have a greedy zip (one preserving all elements)?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41336345/2751851)